# print generic for Rcpp class

Tags: r, printing, rcpp

I have some issues writing a `R` generic printer for a Rcpp class. Think about the Uniform example on page 8 of http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf. I have tried to define a generic like this:

```
# Create new Uniform object:
uniform = Uniform$new(1, 2)
class(uniform)

## [1] "Rcpp_Uniform"
## attr(,"package")
## [1] "uniform"


# Printer for the object:
print.Rcpp_Uniform = function (x, ...) { message("Hi, I am an uniform object") }
```

Now, if I type in just `uniform` I get:

```
C++ object <000000000d825c80> of class 'Uniform' <000000000287b090>
```

But this is what I try to avoid. Calling the printer directly gives what I like to have:

```
print(uniform)
## Hi, I am an uniform object
```

Is there a way to directly use the custom printer without calling the print function?

Comment: I suspect you are desiring an automatic connection between S3 dispatch, and Rcpp Modules. But there isn't one as Modules are in fact implemented as S4 classes.  So I think if you want to add custom printers that is probably where you have to go.

Comment: Ah I see! You are totally right. Didn't think of that. Thanks for that great package! :)

Comment: I _think_ that what you desire is both neat and has not been done before and somewhat orthogonal to Rcpp itself.  So if you were to work this out it might make for a nice addition to the vignette, or as a Rcpp Gallery post, or...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Dirks hint I have a solution. Here is the cpp file `uniform.cpp` which contains the uniform class (copied of Dirks [Rcpp Modules](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf) document) and the Rcpp module definition:

```
// BEGIN uniform.cpp

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class Uniform {
public:
  Uniform(double min_, double max_) : min(min_), max(max_) {}
  NumericVector draw(int n) const {
    RNGScope scope;
    return runif( n, min, max );
  }
  double min, max;
};
double uniformRange( Uniform* w) {
  return w->max - w->min;
}
RCPP_MODULE(unif_module) {
  class_<Uniform>( "Uniform" )
  .constructor<double,double>()
  .field( "min", &Uniform::min )
  .field( "max", &Uniform::max )
  .method( "draw", &Uniform::draw )
  .method( "range", &uniformRange )
  ;
}

// END uniform.cpp
```

Now this can be sourced and used:

```
library(Rcpp)
## Warning: package 'Rcpp' was built under R version 3.4.3

sourceCpp(file = "uniform.cpp")

uniform = Uniform$new(0, 10)

# Default printer:
uniform
## C++ object <00000000137a2e90> of class 'Uniform' <0000000015256dc0>

class(uniform)
## [1] "Rcpp_Uniform"
## attr(,"package")
## [1] ".GlobalEnv"
```

Now the clue is to define the method `show` as custom printer for the S4 class `Rcpp_Uniform`. After that the printer does the desired thing:

```
setMethod("show", class(uniform), function (object) {
  cat("\n Hi, I am an uniform object!\n")
  cat("\n I was initialized with a minimum value of", object$min)
  cat("\n and a maximum value of ", object$max, ".\n", sep = "")
  cat("\n Therefore my range is ", object$range(), ".", sep = "")
  cat("\n\n")
})
## [1] "show"

uniform
## 
##  Hi, I am an uniform object!
## 
##  I was initialized with a minimum value of 0
##  and a maximum value of 10.
## 
##  Therefore my range is 10.
```

---

#### Use in Package

To get that printer as default printer after exposing the `C++` class to `R` within a package it is sufficient to create a `R` file (e.g. `R/uniform_printer.R`) and put the following code in there:

```
setMethod("show", "Rcpp_Uniform", function (object) {
  cat("\n Hi, I am an uniform object!\n")
  cat("\n I was initialized with a minimum value of", object$min)
  cat("\n and a maximum value of ", object$max, ".\n", sep = "")
  cat("\n Therefore my range is ", object$range(), ".", sep = "")
  cat("\n\n")
})
```

Note that it is necessary to reference to the class explicitely by a string (here `Rcpp_Uniform`).

One drawback here is, that this will throw a warning while building the package since there isn't a definition for that class while building the package. The same warning occurs if one runs the `setMethod` function from above in front of sourcing the cpp file.

Something to avoid this warning would be to set a class in front of `setMethod`. This would look like this:

```
setClass("Rcpp_Uniform")
setMethod("show", "Rcpp_Uniform", function (object) {
  cat("\n Hi, I am an uniform object!\n")
  cat("\n I was initialized with a minimum value of", object$min)
  cat("\n and a maximum value of ", object$max, ".\n", sep = "")
  cat("\n Therefore my range is ", object$range(), ".", sep = "")
  cat("\n\n")
})
```

I honestly do not know how appropriate this is. But it works fine within a package.

Comment: Very nice.  Would you be interested in contributing this to the Rcpp Gallery?  I can help with the formatting etc aspects.

Comment: Of course. That would be very nice. Just tell me what you need. :)

Comment: Deal.  And I think we have most of what we need already.  You _could_ check out the rcpp-gallery site, but it is pretty tied to Jekyll.  I think "by now" it just works on recent enough OSs, ie my Ubuntu. You can give that a shot, or we can just share a draft in another way and I then commit it.

Comment: Ah ok, I am not very familiar with Jekyll. But anyway, I think I have to deal with it soon, maybe I should give this a try.

Comment: If/when you have all jekyll pieces on your box (macOS, Ubuntu, ... should all be fine) then `make preview` is all it takes.

Comment: Adding a new piece is then just adding a new file to `src/`. I think we have a 'how to contribute' there...

Comment: One last thing though: the way knitr processes the files had some interaction with Rcpp Modules which may have something to do why we have relatively few posts on Modules...

Comment: Ok, I think I have to figure out how to install all dependencies on my machine. I am working on windows. I will send you an email when I got something.

Comment: Sounds excellent.  Everything tends to be a little harder on Windows.  But yes, can switch to a pull request (or issue ticket first) at the Rcpp Gallery repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161481/discussion-between-daniel-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).